# How to modify default Authorize attribute in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorize

I need to modify the default Authorize attribute so that it redirects to a Not Found view instead of the default Access Denied view, how do i do it?

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it by just using a TStopwatch(uses QueryPerformanceCounter )inside my threads, which also gives me more precise timing(in microseconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this configuration to change **AccessDeniedPath**, **LogoutPath** and **LoginPath** path in `ConfigureServices` method in startup class

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";//<--NOTE THIS
                options.LogoutPath = "/Acconut/LogOut";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
                options.SlidingExpiration = false;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });
    //
}
```

Comment: @DeepakMishra I'm suspicious too. by flag  your comment, i will report to the moderators to check this

Answer (score 1):

You can create a policy (e.g. [Authorize( Policy = "NotFoundPagePlolicy")]) and the policy is registered in the application's Startup.cs to execute some block of code.

In Startup/ConfigureServices() :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("NotFoundPagePlolicy", 
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new Authorization.NotFoundPagePloliyRequirement()));
});
```

In Controller :

```
[Authorize(Policy = "NotFoundPagePlolicy")]
```

In NotFoundPagePloliyRequirement.cs :

```
public class NotFoundPagePloliyRequirement: AuthorizationHandler<NotFoundPagePloliyRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
        public override void Handle(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, NotFoundPagePloliyRequirement requirement)
        {
// Your custom code code 
        }
    }
```

More details , Please refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Could you please share the code of NotFoundPagePolicyHandler?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to override onRedirecttoAccessDenied Event. You can do it inside `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class.

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
            {                    
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;                    
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```